# Is there a way to execute the additem function without modifying values of two pointers?

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-management

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    unsigned long sz;
    char *item;
} itemset;

void additem(char** ram,itemset** items,char* thing){
    unsigned long sz=strlen(thing);
    if (sz > 20000 || sz < 1){return;}
    (**items).item=*ram;
    (*ram)+=sz;
    (**items).sz=sz;
    memcpy((char*)((**items).item),thing,sz);
    (*items)++;
}

void showitems(itemset* items){
    unsigned long ct=1;
    while(items->sz > 0){
        char buf[items->sz+2];
        memset(buf,0,items->sz+2);
        memcpy(buf,items->item,items->sz);
        printf("Item %d: size: %d = %s\n",ct,items->sz,buf);
        items++;ct++;
    }
}

int main(){
    char itembuf[50000];
    itemset* myitems=(itemset*)itembuf;
    char* mp=calloc(1,100000);
    char* wmp=mp;
    itemset* items=myitems;
    additem(&wmp,&myitems,"Test");
    additem(&wmp,&myitems,"Tests");
    additem(&wmp,&myitems,"Tester");
    additem(&wmp,&myitems,"Testing");
    showitems(items);
    printf("%s\n",mp);
    free(mp);

}
```

Upon execution, the correct output is shown on screen as follows:

```
Item 1: size: 4 = Test
Item 2: size: 5 = Tests
Item 3: size: 6 = Tester
Item 4: size: 7 = Testing
TestTestsTesterTesting
```

For the additem function to work, It requires two pointers that automatically get updated. one to update the ram memory address of the text, and one to update the stack memory address of the struct.

I'm wondering if there's a way to update the function and call it so that only one pointer is passed in and updated. For example:

```
additem(&stuff,"Test");
```

I want the overall program functionality to still be the same but I don't want to use fixed char array inside the struct as that would waste valuable memory.

Comment: This question might be better suited on Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can always bundle several values in a struct and pass around pointers to it. You can then write functions for initialising that struct and cleaning it up. The calling code should never have to worry about keeping all the variables in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle everything that belongs to your item-set-cum-char-buffer in a `struct` and then pass pointers to that struct to your functions. When you don't modify the struct, for example when you print the item set, pass a `const` pointer.

You should also provide functions to initialise and clean up the item set, so that the cleint code does not have to worry about the implementation details of the set.

Your code could then look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    size_t length;
    char *str;
} Item;

typedef struct {
    size_t bufsize;         /* fixed size of the char buffer */
    size_t buflen;          /* currently used size of buffer */
    char *buf;
    size_t maxitem;         /* max. number of items */
    size_t count;           /* current number of items */
    Item *item;
} Itemset;

int iset_init(Itemset *iset, size_t maxitem, size_t bufsize)
{
    iset->buflen = 0;
    iset->bufsize = bufsize;
    iset->buf = malloc(bufsize);

    iset->count = 0;
    iset->maxitem = maxitem;
    iset->item = malloc(maxitem * sizeof(*iset->item));

    if (iset->item && iset->buf) return 0;

    free(iset->item);
    free(iset->buf);
    return -1;
}

int iset_add(Itemset *iset, char* str)
{
    size_t sz = strlen(str);

    if (iset->count >= iset->maxitem) return -1;
    if (iset->buflen + sz + 1 > iset->bufsize) return -1;

    iset->item[iset->count].str = &iset->buf[iset->buflen];
    iset->item[iset->count].length = sz;
    iset->count++;

    strcpy(&iset->buf[iset->buflen], str);
    iset->buflen += sz + 1;

    printf("%zu\n", iset->buflen);

    return 0;
}

void iset_show(const Itemset *iset)
{
    size_t i;

    printf("%zu items:\n", iset->count);

    for (i = 0; i < iset->count; i++) {
        printf("[%d] %s (%zu letters)\n",
            i, iset->item[i].str, iset->item[i].length);
    }
}

void iset_free(Itemset *iset)
{
    if (iset) {
        free(iset->buf);
        free(iset->item);
    }

    memset(iset, 0, sizeof(*iset));
}
```

The client code will look a lot tidier:

```
int main()
{
    Itemset iset;

    if (iset_init(&iset, 50, 500) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initialise dict.");
        exit(1);
    }

    iset_add(&iset, "Test");
    iset_add(&iset, "Tests");
    iset_add(&iset, "Tester");
    iset_add(&iset, "Testing");

    iset_show(&iset);    
    iset_free(&iset);

    return 0;
}
```